# Mysql selecting from 2 tables while excluding the whole row if specific data was found

Tags: mysql, sql, select

i have 2 tables that contains the following:

Table 1: patient (Contains almost all info i need)
Table 2: ProcedureLog (Contains the procedures that was done to patients listed in Table 1)

I want to view all patients that have an outstanding balance but i want also to exclude the patients from this list that still have an outstanding balance BUT their procedure log contains specific codes that would identify them as orthodontics cases. i don't any orthodontics case in my report.

in Table 1, there is this info:

```
Patient Name | Patient Number | Estimated Balance
Jon          |    5           |      120
Sara         |    19          |      500
```

in Table 2:

```
Patient Number | Procedure CodeNum
5              |         222
5              |         223
5              |         244
5              |         80*****
19             |         80
19             |         10
```

if i run my query and exclude the value CodeNum that are between 222 and 244 i would still get Patient Jon in the resulted query because he had procedure no 80 which is common. How do i do exclude jon?

```
SELECT distinct patient.Fname,patient.Lname,patient.PatNum,patient.EstBalance 
FROM opendental.patient,opendental.procedurelog 
where EstBalance>=1 
and patient.PatNum = procedurelog.PatNum 
and procedurelog.CodeNum not between 222 and 244;
```

I use distinct because i don't care about the values in table 2, table 2 only helps me identify the list of procedures that patient did.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want `NOT EXISTS` rather than a `JOIN`:

```
SELECT p.Fname, p.Lname, p.PatNum, p.EstBalance 
FROM opendental.patient p
WHERE EstBalance >= 1 AND
      NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                  FROM opendental.procedurelog pl
                  WHERE pl.PatNum = p.PatNum AND
                        pl.CodeNum not between 222 and 244
                 );
```

Comment: i think you should have `between` instead of `not between` in your inner query.

Comment: That did it for me! Thanks a lot, i just had to change not between to between to make it work. Can you please tell me how to add more than one filter? eg between 222 and 224 (and also between 500 and 510) do i need to add the whole subquery again?

Comment: no need to add whole subquery again. You can put it in `OR` condition following way: `pl.PatNum = p.PatNum AND
                        ( (pl.CodeNum between 222 and 244) OR ( pl.CodeNum between 500 and 510))`